# get an attributes class

Tags: c#, class, attributes

Is it possible in C# in an attribute constructor to get the class that has the attribute assigned to it without having to pass that class name in.

```
    [MyAttr]
    public class A{}

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    [Serializable]
    public class MyAttrAttribute: Attribute
    {
        public MyAttrAttribute()
        {
           //get info here about the class A etc
        }    
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  But why would you want to do this? What are you trying to achieve?

When you retrieve an attribute at run time, you do so from the type object representing the class. So even though the information is not stored in the attribute object, it is readily available.

Comment: "you do so from the type object representing the class" - to be clearer, you fetch the attributes from the `Type`, which represents *all* instances of the class... so you don't *necessarily* have an instance available

Comment: I need to put an attribute on each of my classes for auditing purposes and the attribute denotes the auditing buddy class, in just about all cases the buddy class is named the same as the original with "Audit" tacked on the end so I'd like to have a default constructor that when you dont give anythign it uses this default convention

Comment: @Mark, the Type object doesn't represent all instances of the class, it represents the class itself. @Danielhttp, I would make a helper method to get the buddy class; that method would retrieve the attribute, and if the attribute its in its default state (or perhaps if it is missing altogether), that implies the default convention.

Comment: @Mark again: did you think I was implying or assuming he had an instance of the decorated class available? If so, what did I write that gave you that impression?

Comment: Helper method sounds like it will do the trick, been working hard all day and didn't even consider this!

Answer (score 3):

Attribute instances are completely independent of the types/fields/properties that they decorate; there is absolutely no way of accessing the *context* from an attribute. However, attributes also *aren't created* until you explicitly query them with reflection.

If you want to invoke some logic, then it must be done explicitly through code - so you might consider adding a method on your attribute *that accepts the context object*:

```
public void Invoke(object instance) {...}
```

for example, then use GetCustomAttribute to obtain it, cast it, and call `.Invoke()`

Answer (score 0):

This would have been a convenient feature, nice question. But fundamentally attributes are meant only as meta data to inspectors not  to be inspectors - they are constant data.